# Angular 14 : Header buttons disappear when routeLink added inside <a> tag for redirecting to a page

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I am facing an issue while creating a link for header buttons.
I created the header using below code snippet for the project. When I add routeLink inside the `<a>` tag for the [home and Countries] button, both buttons disappear from the head. If I remove it from the `<a>` buttons are shown in the header.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link "  routerLink="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="countries">Countries</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When I check on console The names(Home and Countries) is missing(between) from the '` tag.

How can I fix this?

Comment: this looks fine(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-n2puqj), can you add a reproducible example?(Note: I just removed the collapse class from #navbarNav element for visibility)

Comment: Removing collapse class does not work. And what do you mean by "reproducible example".

Comment: Everything works fine . Till I add routeLink inside the <a> tags

Comment: can you share your app module routing configuration ? hope you have followed the steps for adding routing from [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: thanks for docs. I think I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is form app-routing.module.ts file
try Remove "/" from path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I had put the routes like this before

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "/", component: HomeComponent },
];
```

so just change the routes to

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", component: HomeComponent },
];
```